# Getting the string at nth position using Python in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
lines = sc.textFile(fileName)
```

I am trying to get the string from position 10:20 from every line to do some processing. Since lines are an RDD, it's giving a syntax error saying that there is no `__getitem__`.

Comment: `lines.map(lambda line: line[10:21])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, `lines` is an `RDD` (collection) of `String`s so you need to call something (`substring`) on each element. To get the result of a function call on each member of the RDD, `map` is your friend.

Python (courtesy of @zero323):

```
lines.map(lambda line: line[10:21])
```

Scala:

```
lines.map ( line => line.substring(10,20) )
```

This returns another RDD, so you'll need to write more transformations before your action (ie. return result or write to file), which will trigger it to run.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance what is l here

Comment: This is scala syntax, not python.

Comment: Hey Harish, I've incorporated the python from @zero323 into my answer and made the lambda a bit clearer. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the nth(5th) element by using the following

```
lines.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda keyV: keyV[1]==5).first()[0]
```